# Find the bridge IP address for Philips Hue

Tags: c#, philips-hue

I used the example from the following link [Nuget for HueApi](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.HueApi/)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IBridgeLocator locator = new SSDPBridgeLocator();

    //For Windows 8 and .NET45 projects you can use the SSDPBridgeLocator which actually scans your network. 
    //See the included BridgeDiscoveryTests and the specific .NET and .WinRT projects
    IEnumerable<string> bridgeIPs = locator.LocateBridgesAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    foreach (var bridgeIp in bridgeIPs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(bridgeIp);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I run this console app it doesn't find the bridge ip address. Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong? I verified that the bridge of Philips Hue is working fine.

How can I automatically find the Philips Hue bridge in a network?

Which credentials should I run the console app on?

Comment: *"Which credentials should I run the console app on?"* - Administrator?

Comment: Previously i tried to run as admin and it failed. But now i am able to run it successfully. Thanks for your answer

Comment: So did that actually solve the problem?

Comment: @Ben : It started failing again. I am unable to retrieve the IP address. No code change. Any ideas what thing might have caused this. Seems like a network issue to me. And for couple of runs it looked like it had solved the issue

Comment: That's seeming likely. Monitor your network status when you run this to double check :)

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: Here is the code link : https://github.com/Q42/Q42.HueApi/blob/master/src/Q42.HueApi.NET/SSDPBridgeLocator.cs  I restarted my PC and it worked fine. Still trying to figure out what the issue is

Comment: Clean and rebuild the project and run it as admin and it worked.

Comment: So, after all that, did you manage to solve the problem? If so, please feel free to add it as an answer below (you may even get a few upvotes for solving your own problem! That's always worth a few kudos). Make sure to add the details of the issue and what you did to solve them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem that i was facing : After i consumed the [Nuget for HueApi](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.HueApi/) and did a build and tried to run the code it used to succeed at times to retrieve the bridge IP address, But failed at other times.

Some of the things that i made sure that i ran successfully all the time :
1) Run as Admin as mentioned by Ben in the comments
2) Do a clean and rebuild and then try to run the application.